# Quando é que «hipótese» adquiriu o significado de «possibilidade, chance»?

Tags: etimologia, mudanças-históricas

A palavra [***hipótese*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/hip%C3%B3tese) é hoje usada frequentemente com o significado de ‘possibilidade, chance’, mas inicialmente era apenas um termo culto que significava ‘suposição’ e coisas assim. Por exemplo, ainda em 1874, D. José M. A. A. Corrêa de Lacerda no seu [*Diccionario Encyclopedico*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=boJHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA314&dq=%22Theoria%20provavel,%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20demonstrada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPp9vx-NrOAhWGPhQKHeU3CjwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Theoria%20provavel%2C%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20demonstrada%22&f=false) tinha apenas (grafia original):

> HYPÓTHESE, ou HYPOTHESIS, *s. f. (hypo*, pref. e *these)* conjectura, supposição fundada sobre factos e razões provaveis; theoria provavel, mas não demonstrada; *ex*. A existencia do calorico e da electricidade como elementos é uma —. Pron. o accento na ante-penultima.
> Syn. comp. *Hypothese, supposição. Hypothese* é temo philosophico; *supposição* é familiar. O sentido proprio e primitivo de *hypothese* é ponto controvertido em juizo.

Este é basicamente o único significado que continuam a ter os cognatos inglês [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypothesis), francês [(Larousse)](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/hypoth%C3%A8se/41267?q=hypothese#41163) e castelhano [(Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KUtnGU1). Ao contrário, no português atual, pelo menos em Portugal, o seu uso mais frequente é no entanto no sentido de ‘possibilidade, chance’. Exemplos:

> Bola de ouro: Figo diz que Ronaldo tem hipótese de ganhar, mas… [[Mais Futebol (Portugal), 15-12-2015]](http://www.maisfutebol.iol.pt/luis-figo/cristiano-ronaldo/bola-de-ouro-figo-diz-que-ronaldo-tem-hipoteses-de-ganhar-mas)
>
> As duplas masculinas do Brasil não têm hipótese de se enfrentarem antes da disputa por medalha no torneio de Vôlei de Praia dos Jogos Olímpicos Rio 2016 [[Folha de São Paulo, 24-8-2016.]](http://fotografia.folha.uol.com.br/galerias/45766-o-dia-olimpico)
>
> A Islândia tem de trabalhar mais e ser mais organizada que o adversário para ter hipóteses de ganhar [[*O País* (Angola), 27-6-2016.]](http://opais.co.ao/euro-tem-final-antecipada/)

**Quando é que *hipótese* adquiriu este significado? Alguém consegue documentar a transição dos significados originais até ao sentido de ‘possibilidade, chance’?**

Comment: Até julho passado eu não conhecia esse significado da palavra hipótese.  Foi então durante minha viagem de avião pela Air Portugal que resolvi assistir ao filme "Gran Torino" (excelente filme, por sinal) com legendas em pt-PT.  Em dado momento ouço o protagonista dizer: "That boy won't have a chance", o que foi traduzido como "esse rapaz não tem hipótese".   Fiquei intrigado com esse uso da palavra e assim que pude consultei um dicionário. Live and learn.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu também não tinha a certeza que este sentido de *hipótese* existisse no Brasil, porque ouço normalmente é *chance*, que em Portugal pouco se usa. Mas encontra-se esse uso no Brasil, como o exemplo que eu cito. Agora é verdade que quando se procura no Google ***tem hipótese***, os resultados vêm desproporcionalmente de Portugal.

Comment: São intercambiáveis em outras frases?  Por exemplo, em pt-PT, alguem dizer "ela merece uma segunda hipótese"  (chance) ?

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, é possível "uma segunda hipótese", mas "uma segunda oportunidade" seria o mais comum.

Comment: Nunca me tinha apercebido da necessidade de uma transição lol ainda que já tivesse usado por diversas vezes em ambos sentidos. Gostei desta pergunta! +1

Comment: Que nó cego, para mim é tão natural isso que nunca tinha reparado. E estou dificuldades em pensar sobre o assunto.

Comment: @JorgeB. É verdade, para nós é muito natural. Mas os dois sentidos são claramente distintos. Eu creio se me apercebi quando vivi em Inglaterra: em inglês *hypothesis* nunca é usado com o sentido de 'possibilidade, chance'; por outro lado no meu estudo e trabalho usava muito o termo no sentido original.

Comment: Parece uma expressão idiomática esse "ter hipótese".

Comment: @bfavaretto *Hipótese*, talvez mais em Portugal que no Brasil, passou a significar também 'possibilidade', e *possibilidade* também significa 'oportunidade'; logo *ter hipótese = ter possibilidade = ter oportunidade*. Creio que de *a hipótese (construção mental) dos universos paralelos é especulativa* confunde-se com *a possibilidade (realidade) de existirem universos paralelos é remota*, e vai daí *hipótese* e *possibilidade* confundiram-se, e já se diz também *hipótese remota*; mas dirias *conjetura/suposição remota*? ou *especultiva, provavelmente errada*?

Comment: Jamais vi esse uso em pt-BR. Infelizmente a referência da Folha de São Paulo é apenas uma legenda de uma foto, sem autoria registrada — pois eu acharia que a hipótese mais provável é o autor ser falante de pt-PT e seria interessante verificar se ela se confirma. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hipótese" tem esse uso já há bastante tempo.

O problema é que "hipótese" foi adotada para uso quotidiano sem a definição formal cientifica, dada na pergunta do Jacinto.

Data pelo menos de 1821, no livro ["Diario das cortes geraes e extraordinarias da nação portugeza"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ec1OAAAAYAAJ&q=hip%C3%B3tese&dq=hip%C3%B3tese&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS9uSJtO7QAhXpA8AKHQnlC6QQ6AEIHDAA). A palavra hipótese aparece somente uma vez com o mesmo significado/conotação da pergunta.

> Apoio esta doutrina. He mui possivel a hipotese de uma crise em que
>   seja tal a affluencia de bilhetes ao banco, que elle não possa realisalos.

Repare-se que a palavra hipótese não está a ser usada no contexto cientifico.

Eu posso fazer uma conjetura em como a palavra hipótese veio a tomar esse significado. Segundo a definição dada na pergunta, Ênfase minha

> HYPÓTHESE, ou HYPOTHESIS, s. f. (hypo, pref. e these) conjectura, supposição fundada sobre factos e **razões provaveis**; theoria **provavel**, **mas não demonstrada**

Nesta definição cabe ao leitor decidir qual é o significado que a palavra provável deve tomar. [A palavra "provável"](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/prov%C3%A1vel) pode tomar o significado de comprovável ou de poder vir a acontecer.

Na minha perspectiva eu diria que estão ambos corretos, ora veja-se:

Uma hipótese pode ser refutada/provada em contrário. Logo as razoes que levaram a essa hipótese eram prováveis, mas certamente que não eram comprováveis. Elas teriam sido comprováveis se alguém tivesse usado exactamente os mesmos métodos e mecanismos para obter o mesmo resultado. (claro que na prática acaba ser um pouco mais difícil do que isto demonstrar que a hipótese nao era correta)

Ou seja o moral da história é que "hipótese" ainda tem um elemento de incerteza, ainda é necessário usar mecanismos, provas adicionais, provas de ocorrencia no mundo real,... para ela vir potencialmente a ser considerada uma teoria.

Já quando a hipótese é considerada uma teoria então as razoes eram quer prováveis (pois poderia ter acontecido o contrário), quer prováveis (pois foi comprovado que a hipótese é verdadeira)

Creio que seja este fator de incerteza que tenha levado a cabo o uso de "hipótese" como provável (pode vir a acontecer).

Comment: Bem, desta vez caprichaste, +1! Há quase duzentos anos--não tava nada à espera. Interessante a grafia 'moderna'. Agora, a tua primeira frase parece ser uma resposta ("Porque" [...]), mas não sei a que pergunta; certamente não a pergunta que eu tenha feito.

Comment: Tu pareces sugerir que a diferença entre as duas aceções é apenas o campo a que a palavra aplicada. Mas não é. Conjetura e possibilidade de algo vir a ocorrer são coisas diferentes. 'Conjetura' não é apenas a definição que eu apresento na pergunta; é a definição original e a única que ainda hoje é válida para os cognatos inglês, francês, e espanhol. Nota que *hipótese provável* e *acontecimento provável* usam a palavra provável em sentidos diferentes.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu aceito isso jacinto. Mas no meu ponto de vista o moral da história é que hipótese é algo que ainda pode ser refutado. Por isso tens dois caminhos, nao ser refutado e ser refutado. Ou seja ela é fundamentalmente também uma possibilidade. Tal como disse na minha resposta esse parece ter sido o motivo do seu surgimento com o significado que sugeriste.

Comment: @Jacinto Já entendi melhor o teu comentário, vou editar a resposta devidamente

Comment: Ficou melhor assim. Talvez a melhor maneira de ver a diferença é 1) no sentido original podemos substituir *hipótese* por *conjetura* --*a existência de universos paralelos é uma conjetura*--mas 2) no sentido 'quotidiano' não podemos--não podemos dizer _*o Ronaldo tem conjetura de ganhar_.

Comment: @Jacinto Exatamente :)

Comment: Sou economista, tinha que completar a citação :)

Comment: "Cartes* é engano do Google. Se desceres na página, vez que aquilo é *cortes*. Aquilo foi um debate parlamentar.

Comment: Aqui discordo. O autor é do século XIX-XX:  [Augusto Pires de Lima (1883-1959)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusto_C%C3%A9sar_Pires_de_Lima). Mas mais importante, a distinção relevante não é domínio científico versus não científico; é *conjetura ou construção mental* versus *possibilidade de algo acontecer*. Neste caso o autor refere-se a uma conjetura avançada por um Garrett, possivelmente o Almeida Garrett (1799-1854). Tu podes ter uma hipótese/conjetura acerca da origem de um texto, que parece ser o que o texto trata.

Comment: Mas eu acho que até seria interessante ter também exemplos, tão antigos quanto possíveis de *hipótese* no seu sentido 'conjetura'. Mas este é já do sXX.

Comment: @Jacinto Nao procede. Se vires a capa do livro ves claramente lá escrito "Escrito por Bento Teixeira PInto". O autor [Bento teixeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento_Teixeira) é mais conhecido pela obra "PROSOPOPEIA" também de 1601.

Comment: O mais relevante é que *hipótese* é usado como 'conjetura'; não  'possibilidade'. Quanto à questão secundária, a linguagem não é do século XVII. A grafia é do sXX; "tôda", indica que é da primeira metade. Isto deve ser o livro do Bento Teixeira com introdução do Augusto Pires de Lima. Os excertos devem ser da introdução, em que o Pires de Lima discute a origem do texto e comenta as opiniões de Alemeida Garret sobre o assunto.

Comment: Pronto, tens [aqui o livro completo](http://www.brasiliana.usp.br/bitstream/handle/1918/01484400/014844_COMPLETO.pdf)  mas sem o Pires de Lima; não encontro nem *hipotese* nem *hypothese*; nem *síntese*, nem nenhuma palavra dos excertos do Google.

Comment: @Jacinto De fato... nao faz sentido estar a falar de Garret sem ele ter sequer nascido. mas a explicacao anterior serviu

Answer (score 1):

Hipótese no Brasil é apenas... hipótese, nunca possibilidade ou chance.

Mas a lógica da inovação semântica parece ser a seguinte:

*O Benfica não perde hoje para o Porto em **hipótese alguma.*** Ou seja, o Benfica não perderá o jogo, nem mesmo se, hipoteticamente, todos os seus jogadores estiverem gripados, entrarem em greve, perderem o vôo para o Porto, ou os deuses do futebol decidirem apoiar o Porto. Aqui "hipótese" ainda significa hipótese, mas já indica, de certa forma, que o Porto não tem possibilidade ou chance de vencer o jogo. Daí o próximo passo parece ser, *O Porto não tem **hipótese** de vitória no jogo de hoje.* Já que não vencerá em hipótese alguma, "não tem hipótese de vitória".

(Disclaimer: Sim, eu sei que o Porto às vezes ganha do Benfica. Como dizem as propagandas de sanduíche fast food, trata-se de imagem meramente ilustrativa.)

---

No google, as ocorrências mais antigas de "não tem hipótese" que encontro são de 1999, mas ambas são documentos oficiais (um paper da Universidade do Porto e um documento da Câmara Municipal de Vizeu). Já para "não tem hipóteses", no plural, encontro um paper acadêmico moçambicano de Carlos Nuno Castel-Branco para a Universidade Eduardo Mondlane de 1983, [A INTEGRAÇÃO DOS CAMPONESES MÉDIOS NUMA ECONOMIA SOCIALISTA PLANIFICADA](http://www.iese.ac.mz/lib/cncb/CEA_83_Camponeses_medios.pdf).

Receio, portanto, que a transição tenha ocorrido antes do advento da internet, a não ser que tenha se originado no próprio ambiente acadêmico.

Comment: Na minha citação da Folha de São Paulo, *hipótese* significa *possibilidade* ou *chance*, ao contrário do que tu afirmas. A transição semântica não é difícil de compreender. Mas a pergunta é: **quando é que isso aconteceu?**

Comment: Por essas e outras a Folha é popularmente conhecida como "Falha de São Paulo"... mas, sim, "nunca" é um exagero, melhor seria, "nunca, a não ser que estejas a escrever para o jornalão mais metido a besta da história do Brasil."

Comment: No Brasil usamos sim hipótese como possibilidade/chance, mesmo que na verdade o sentido mais correto seja para coisas "hipotéticas".

Comment: Há exemplos mais antigos. No Google Books, [1938](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oMhbAAAAMAAJ): _É frequente ver-se Lúcia tomada de uma intensa curiosidade, crivar a professora de perguntas que esta,  é claro, já espera, depois de haver preparado o ambiente. Não há hipótese de cansaço nem enfastiamento, o que é comum nos velhos processos de obrigar o aluno a decorar e compreender as regras que ele detesta e que não pode nem quer compreender._

Answer (score 1):

A citação da *Folha de São Paulo* na pergunta pode ser entendida (eu certamente a entendi) como sendo um elemento de alternativa:

> As duplas masculinas do Brasil não têm hipótese de se enfrentarem antes da disputa por medalha no torneio de Vôlei de Praia dos Jogos Olímpicos Rio 2016, de acordo com o sorteio realizado na noite desta quinta-feira (11.08) na Arena de Copacabana. ([Mesma fonte acima, com o resto da legenda](http://fotografia.folha.uol.com.br/galerias/45766-o-dia-olimpico))

Neste caso, o jornalista afirmava que não havia combinação de resultados de jogos então futuros que possibilitassem as duplas masculinas se enfrentarem antes das semifinais, devido à maneira em que as duplas foram distribuídas nas chaves pelo sorteio, e não que fosse muito ou pouco provável esse encontro.

Comment: Wtrmute, não chegaste a responder à pergunta: quando é que *hipótese* começou a ser usado com o significado de 'possibilidade, coisa que possa vir a acontecer'.

Comment: Wtrmute, andei a revisitar estas coisas antigas, e sim, é e foi esse o meu entendimento também. Mas esse é o uso "novo", no sentido ’possibilidade, chance’. Se dizes que "**não** tem possibilidade, chance", então, como dizes, não é muito nem pouco provável; é impossível; se dissesses que "tem possibilidade", então é que pode ser mais ou menos provável, não sendo garantido nem impossível.